# How to add an autocomplete feature for text filed in eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing an eclipse plugin. In that, the first page will be authentication page.

And the code written for that is

```
this.urlLabel = new Label(loginPanel, SWT.NONE);
    this.urlLabel.setText("Server URL");
    this.server = new Text(loginPanel, SWT.BORDER);

    this.usernameLabel = new Label(loginPanel, SWT.NONE);
    this.usernameLabel.setText("Username");
    this.username = new Text(loginPanel, SWT.BORDER);

    this.passwordLabel = new Label(loginPanel, SWT.NONE);
    this.passwordLabel.setText("Password");
    this.password = new Text(loginPanel, 4196352);
```

So what I want to do is, for the URL,username when I start typing it should suggest me with the previously typed values.
How to do that.
Help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.AutoCompleteField` for this.

For a text control use:

```
new AutoCompleteField(control, new TextContentAdapter(), proposals);
```

where `control` is a `Text` control (such as your `username`).

`proposals` is an array of strings containing the previous values you want auto complete to use.

You can call the `setProposals` method of `AutoCompleteField` to update the proposals array.

Comment: Thanks, @greg-449. It's working but here proposals have been populated before itself. I need to suggest them based on their previously entered values.

Comment: That is up to you to save the previous values somewhere, Eclipse won't do that for you. You can call `setProposals` to update the proposals array (updated answers)